# Redshift in Ubuntu will lose effect for a while

Tags: redshift

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 on my laptop, and installed Redshift from the official software center. There's one problem that annoyed me for a long time. The thing is: sometimes for no reason Redshift will just lose effect for about  1-2 seconds, the screen get back to white.
Has anyone run into this and know how to fix it ?

Comment: FWIW, I’ve seen this with games running in wine. They sometimes fight with redshift over the gamma/colour correction settings.

Comment: I doesn't install wine and any extra games in my Ubuntu   :-(